# How to run Python Package on the command line in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pip, package

I have installed a Python package like this:

```
pip install uncompyle6
```

The [PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/uncompyle6/#usage) says I should enter these lines on the terminal to use the tool or to get help:

```
$ uncompyle6 *compiled-python-file-pyc-or-pyo*

$ uncompyle6 -h
```

But it doesn't work on Windows. Which file do I have to run to achieve the same result?

`uncompyle6` was installed to `C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages`. The `C:\Python39\Scripts` folder only contains three files (`pip.exe` `pip3.9.exe` `pip3.exe`) and no uncompyle6 script.

I have read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/859946/i-installed-a-python-package-on-windows-using-pip-why-cant-i-call-it-from-the) question which tells you to run `python.exe` followed by the script name (or path). Windows doesn't run `.py` files automatically and the `PATH` variable entry for the installed packages might be missing. But where do I find the right file that is run when you simply enter `uncompyle6` in the terminal on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

try to run:

```
$ python -m uncompyle6 *compiled-python-file-pyc-or-pyo*
$ python -m uncompyle6 -h
```

Comment: It says `C:\python-decompile-test\>python -m uncompyle6 -h` `C:\Python39\python.exe: No module named uncompyle6.__main__; 'uncompyle6' is a package and cannot be directly executed`. If it is a package and cannot be directly executed, why does it tell you to run `$ uncompyle6 -h` in the _Usage_ section on the homepage of the tool? It probably does work on Linux. How to get it working on Windows?